# improperly derived Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers::ToggleElem class

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome

I have an improperly derived Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers::ToggleElem class from the 
gtkglextmm libraries.

Is anyone familiar with these GNOME classes? I can't find a recent version of the docs.

```
    //
// C++ Interface: tooltogglebutton
//
// Description: 
//
//
// Author: Karsten Bohlmann <aldaran@users.sourceforge.net>, (C) 2004
//
// Copyright: See COPYING file that comes with this distribution
//
//
#ifndef TOOLTOGGLEBUTTON_H
#define TOOLTOGGLEBUTTON_H

#include <gtkmm/toolbar.h>


/**
provides Gtk::toolbar togglebutton with extra access methods

@author Karsten Bohlmann
*/
class ToolToggleButton : public Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers::ToggleElem 
{
public:
  ToolToggleButton(const Glib::ustring& text,
   const SigC::Slot0<void> & callback,
   const Glib::ustring& tooltip_text = Glib::ustring(), 
   const Glib::ustring& tooltip_private_text = Glib::ustring());
  ~ToolToggleButton();
  void setActive (bool isActive);  
};

#endif
```

causes the following errors:

```
In file included from cellapp.h:27:0,
                 from cellapp.cpp:23:
tooltogglebutton.h:23:38: error: ‘Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers’ has not been declared
 class ToolToggleButton : public Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers::ToggleElem::ToggleElem 
                                      ^
tooltogglebutton.h:23:67: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘ToggleElem’
 class ToolToggleButton : public Gtk::Toolbar_Helpers::ToggleElem::ToggleElem 
                                                                   ^
tooltogglebutton.h:24:1: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
tooltogglebutton.h:24:1: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
tooltogglebutton.h:25:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘public’
 public:
 ^
tooltogglebutton.h:25:1: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘public’
tooltogglebutton.h:25:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘public’
tooltogglebutton.h:30:22: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token
   ~ToolToggleButton();
                      ^
tooltogglebutton.h:32:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 };
 ^
make[2]: *** [cellapp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dave/src/cellumat3d/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dave/src/cellumat3d'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to include specific gtkmm header files; only `<gtkmm/gtkmm.h>`. I'm not 100% sure though; that *is* the case for GTK+ itself, though.

Comment: Ok thanks for that I'll try it out and get back to you!